# How to wait async operation within class constructor?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a class costructor:

```
public AllSignalsViewModel()
    {
        LoadSignals();
        fetchMoreDataCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            obj =>
                {
                    if (busy)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Busy = true;
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                        delegate
                        {
                            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                                delegate 
                                {
                                    AddMoreItems();
                                    Busy = false;

                                });
                        });                 
            });
    }
```

LoadSignals() is an async function, but I need to let it ends, before the running of the following code. But I can't await it, because I can't set the constructor as async. What I should to do?

Here is a LoadSignals() function:

```
private async void LoadSignals()
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDataSource();
        var sigCol = new SignalCollection(xmlDocument);
        var region = GetRegionInSettingsStorage();
        var allSignals = await sigCol.LoadSignals(isVotes(), false, region);
        signalSchema = allSignals;
        AddMoreItems();

    }
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing an InitializeAsync method which gets called in the code behind (or even in the constructor without await).

But LoadSignals must return task otherwise you cannot await it...

Comment: It will not solve my problem, because It impossible to make fetchMoreDataCommand = new DelegateCommand(...) outside the constructor. =(

Comment: then you have to check inside of the command if the load signals has completed and wait for it if necessary...